# String interpolation: a bug in c# compiler?

Tags: c#, string, interpolation, compiler-bug

`string Test(bool @bool) => $"you're {@bool?"hired":"fired"} Have a nice day!";`

The code above results in compilation error.
But why?
Notice that 
`string test = $"this {"is"} working";`
works.

Comment: What compilation error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colon ends the interpolation. Just parenthesize the condition :

```
string Test(bool @bool) => $"you're {(@bool ? "hired":"fired")} Have a nice day!";
```

Answer (score 1):

For this issue you you can not use of `?,:` of some thing like these, for using of these you have to set Exactly your condition should put in `()` like:

```
string Test(bool @bool) => $"you're {(@bool ? "hired":"fired")} Have a nice day!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `()` contain your `?:` Operator

```
string Test(bool @bool) => $"you're {(@bool ? "hired":"fired")} Have a nice day!";
```

[$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)